# npm install 403 issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install bower as follow -

```
$ npm install -g bower or $npm install bower

npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.7.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.7.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.7.1.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-16-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/ravi/watson/novus/nvd3/npm-debug.log
```

I already have npm proxy setting in place as shown in example below :

```
    npm config list
    ; cli configs
    user-agent = "npm/2.11.3 node/v0.12.7 linux ppc64"

    ; userconfig /root/.npmrc
    http-proxy = "https://username:password@:8080/"
    https-proxy = "https://username:password@:8080/"
    proxy = "https://username:password@:8080/"
    registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
    strict-ssl = false

    ; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
    ; cwd = /root/ravi/watson/novus/nvd3
    ; HOME = /root
    ; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

Comment: Use sudo npm install -g bower I think it works

Comment: with sudo also having same issue

Answer (score 2):

The vm in which I was trying is proxyless. So I deleted all proxies from the npm config setting. Then npm install worked fine. The proxy is for those who are beyond the proxies.